# Reducing iOS app size with large audio files

Tags: ios, audio, size

I currently have an app that has 5 .mp3 files for users to listen to audio to. There are then PNGs associated with each file. It's a simple click and play app. The current app size, however, is 88MB - obviously very large.

I am looking at trying to reduce this in whatever way possible and not sure what the most effective ways are - particularly for the audio.

It is for iOS9.3 upwards as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to compress the mp3 audio using a lower bitrate, but this will affect the audio quality, just google "compress mp3" and try one of the sites there and see if the file size reduced to what you need with good quality or not.

Another solution is to compress the mp3 file to zip file and decompress it at runtime. Try different compression ratios to get minimum size without having a bad user experience by waiting too long for the decompression. Keep in mind that you may want to write the decompressed file to the device temporarily, so you won't run out of memory. These are some libraries for zipping and unzipping files: [1](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive), [2](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip), [3](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation).

Or you may use these solutions together to get the best result.